# How to add TextView in SlidingDrawer using code?

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I am new to `Android` and this is my first question on `Android`.

I am trying to add `TextView` in `Sliding Drawer` dynamically but nothing get displayed after clicking handle button while running on emulator.

This what I have done so far :-

Java code:-

```
SlidingDrawer drawer = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        TextView view = new TextView(this);
        view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        view.setHeight(10);
        view.setWidth(40);
        view.setId(i);
        view.setText("Text " + String.valueOf(i));
        drawer.addView(view);   
    }
```

---

There is no error on `logcat`.

Please help.

Comment: use WRAP_CONTENT instead of MATCH_PARENT...how can you add 10 text views whoose width and height exactly matches parent?

Comment: @JigarPandya I tried `WRAP_CONTENT` but still same problem. Any thing else to do?

Comment: Perhaps change the RelativeLayout.LayoutParams to LinearLayout.LayoutParams?

Comment: @MikeM. First I tried with `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` but it didn't worked.. So I changed it to `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` and that also didn't worked. Please give some more suggestions.

Comment: @AJ. : You have to add your text views in RelativeLayout or Linear Layout inside Sliding drawer.not directly into sliding drawer

Comment: @JigarPandya Ok... Let me try

Comment: I'm posting it as my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this layout..add your text views to Linear layout inside Sliding drawer not directly inside sliding Drawer

```
  <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:handle="@+id/slideButton"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:padding="10dip"
         >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/slideButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:rotation="180"
            android:text="Open" >
        </Button>


         <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#99FF0000"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:padding="10dip"
            >



           <ListView
              android:id="@+id/list"
              android:rotation="180"
              android:layout_height="150dp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent">
           </ListView>

            <ImageView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                 android:rotation="180"

                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>


           </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion.. It works for individual layouts but if the layout is inside `slidingdrawer` then it does not work. For example if I add something inside `contentLayout` dynamically  then it does not work.

Comment: It wont be added because of limited height of sliding drawer.solution is either you make sliding drawer scrollable or remove other views from it and keep enough space in it so 10 text views can be added at run time

Comment: I was facing same issue..cause of limited height of Sliding drawer!! I made enough room so I was able to add 10 text views dynamically